# Get recent count from a column

Tags: mysql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I would like to get the count of a column based on its recent status.

Please see table structure below:

```
id | visible |      date
1  |     1   |   2021-07-22
2  |     1   |   2021-07-23
3  |     0   |   2021-07-24
4  |     1   |   2021-07-25
5  |     0   |   2021-07-26
6  |     0   |   2021-07-27
```

For example, if I query

```
SELECT COUNT(visible) AS latest_not_visible WHERE date = '2021-07-26'
```

then it should return

```
latest_not_visible
      1
```

Since it only counts that date as not visible, it disregarded the count on 07/24 since 07/25 is visible

But if I query

```
SELECT COUNT(visible) AS latest_not_visible WHERE date = '2021-07-27'



latest_not_visible
      2
```

since 07/26 and 07/27 are both non-visible and no date in between is visible

I already had the solution to the problem, but I would need help in optimizing this function:

```
 IIF(datediff
        (day,
        (SELECT MAX(date) FROM t1 WHERE (visible = 0 OR visible = '-1' OR visible = '-3') AND item_id = vp.item_id AND [date] <= vp.date),
        (SELECT MAX(date) FROM t1 WHERE visible = 1 AND item_id = vp.item_id AND [date] <= vp.date)) IS NULL 
            OR datediff(day,
                        (SELECT MAX(date) FROM t1 WHERE (visible = 0 OR visible = '-1' OR visible = '-3') AND item_id = vp.item_id AND [date] <= vp.date),
                        (SELECT MAX(date) FROM t1 WHERE visible = 1 AND item_id = vp.item_id AND [date] <= vp.date)) < 0, 
 (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t1 WHERE (visible = 0 OR visible = '-1' OR visible = '-3') AND item_id = vp.item_id AND [date] <= vp.date), 0) 
 AS times_not_visible,
 
 table vp is the original table same with t1
```

Comment: Why don't you use a procedure or function?

Comment: @Ronald you should use the AND visible=0 and date BETWEEN condition

Comment: Can we guarantee that there will be one result for every single day?

Comment: @JS Bach: You mean "row" not "result". I was going to ask the same. And if days can be missing, say no entry for 2021-07-25, and we count for day 2021-07-27, then what is the expected result? 3 (0 zeros in days 24, 26, 27)? 4 (with day 25 considered a missing zero day)? 2 (with day 25 considered a non-zero day)?

Comment: hi all, assumptions are that there are data for each day (may be visible 1 or 0)

Comment: `COUNT(visible)` determines how many rows have `visible IS NOT NULL`.  See also `SUM()` (which won't solve your problem either.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than counting them, you're better to calculate the number of days between the last visible and not visible on or before that date. So something like this...

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(
   SELECT MAX(date) FROM YourTable WHERE visible = 0 AND date <= '2021-07-27'),
   SELECT MAX(date) FROM YourTable WHERE visible = 1 AND date <= '2021-07-27')
) as latest_not_visible;
```

Comment: Is it better? Can we qualify that somehow?

Comment: Fails for edge case `2021-07-25`

Comment: @SalmanA For scenarios like the 25th you'd get a negative number of days back which would tell you that it is/was visible so that can then be easily handled by whatever ran the query

Comment: hi @DazzKnowles may I ask your help for optimization of my query? I posted it above. It is mainly based on your answer

Comment: @Ronald It's hard to optimise a query without knowing a lot more about the data and environment but to start with I'd make it a little more readable and have `visible IN (0, -1, -3)` rather than all those OR's. I'd also add an index covering all three columns - try id, date, visible for its column order.

Answer (score 1):

Find the latest visible date earlier than the given date and count all rows in between those two dates:

```sql
SET @dt = '2021-07-25';
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t
WHERE date <= (SELECT date FROM t WHERE date = @dt AND visible = 0)
AND   date >  (SELECT date FROM t WHERE date < @dt AND visible = 1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ee4ef/4)

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(visible) - CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM visible)) latest_not_visible 
FROM (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(visible ORDER BY date SEPARATOR '') visible
  FROM tablename
  WHERE date <= ?
) t
```

Change `?` to the date you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87c60d0991bfbfe19b265805f6904c95).

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*,
             max(case when visible = 1 then date end) over (order by date) as max_visible_date
      from t
      where date <= '2021-07-26'    -- or whatever
     ) t
where visible = 0 and
      (date > max_visible_date or max_visible_date is null);
```

Note that this version only mentions the date once.  It also works for if there are no rows with `visible = 1`, and it works on any number of rows.